# Load 2 json output text object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Please help, I want to load 2 JSONs from 2 URLs, this loads questions for a survey. If I just load 1 JSON, the output still normal, but if 2 JSONs, the output is the text `object`, this survey is survey js from surveyjs.io, there is my code. Please help me.

```
var baris1,baris2 = [];
var url1='url_link';
var url2='url_link';

$.when($.getJSON('url_link'),     $.getJSON('url_link')
).done(function(baris1,baris2){
  //baris = data
  baris1 = JSON.stringify(s.baris1)
 baris2 = JSON.stringify(s.baris2);
  //alert(baris1);

Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrap";

 var surveyJSON = {pages:[{elements:[
    {type:"matrix",columns:[
        {value:1,text:"Strongly Disagree"},
        {value:2,text:"Disagree"},
        {value:3,text:"Neutral"},
        {value:4,text:"Agree"},
    {value:5,text:"Strongly Agree"}],
//name:"Pedagogik",rows:baris,
name:"Pedagogik",rows:baris1,
//title:"Silakan Jawab Dengan Sejujur-jujurnya"
},
{type:"matrix",columns:[
    {value:1,text:"Strongly Disagree"},
    {value:2,text:"Disagree"},
    {value:3,text:"Neutral"},
    {value:4,text:"Agree"},
    {value:5,text:"Strongly Agree"}],
//name:"Pengetahuan Umum",rows:baris,
name:"Pengetahuan Umum",rows:baris2,
//title:"Silakan Jawab Dengan objektif"
}]}]}

function sendDataToServer(survey) {
//send Ajax request to your web server.
alert("The results are:" + JSON.stringify(s.data));}

var survey = new      Survey.Model(surveyJSON);
$("#surveyContainer").Survey({
    model: survey,
    onComplete: sendDataToServer
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer, just declare the  number of array for the output,

```
  Row: baris1;
```

Change to

```
Row: baris1,[0];
```

Just it